# how to display on screen numeric keyboard in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, on-screen-keyboard

Now in my application, I have a **Textbox** for entering amount. As amount always deals with numbers, I just dont like a normal (character) keyboard poping up, when the TextBox is on focus.
 What should I do, so that when I click my TextBox, a numeric on screen keyboard should appear in front of me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [InputScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521152%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property to indicate which kind of keyboard must be displayed.

For instance, to display a numeric keyboard:

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number" />
```